# How do I silence "Galaxy Apps"?

Tags: notifications, samsung-galaxy-s-4, ringtone

By "Galaxy Apps" I don't mean "apps installed on my Galaxy S4", I specifically mean the app called "Galaxy Apps". Apparently, the purpose of the app is to keep <strike>the pre-installed junk that cannot be removed</strike> Samsung's own apps up-to-date.

Just like "Play Store", "Galaxy Apps" shows a notification in the notification tray when updates are available. That's a good thing. However, unlike "Play Store", "Galaxy Apps" makes a noise when doing so. The noise is the same as the default SMS notification tone. That's a bad thing (or, at least, an annoyance), because it makes me think that I got some important text message when, in fact, I didn't.

To make a long story short: Can I somehow tell "Galaxy Apps" to:

- do tell me when updates are available (I don't want security issues on my mobile phone just because <strike>some junk that I don't use</strike> some pre-installed application is not up-to-date), but
- be silent while doing so?